# form method post using php

Tags: php, forms, methods, http-post

I'm trying to make a simple form that echo's the answer with php to another page.
I have an html sheet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <form action="gegevens.php" method="post">
        First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
        Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form> 

</body>
</html>
```

**and a php sheet**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <?php
        $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
        $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];

        echo "Firstname: ". $firstname . ".<br />";
        echo "Lastname : ". $lastname. ;
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work when I run it in a browser.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: That period after `$lastname` is redundant

Answer (score 2):

It cannot work in a mere browser. You need to run it with a webserver such as: [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html)

---

PHP (PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor) is a scripting language not a markup language. Opposite to html where you write static xml pages with php you are writing scripts that produce output. Therefore it needs an interpreter to process that script.

See http://php.net/

Answer (score 0):

As @dot-sp0t stated, you need to have some time of webserver running behind the PHP code. The web browser does not have PHP webserver built into it.

Suggestions (Thanks to @dot-sp0t for this one): [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html)

[PHP Built in Webserver](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php)

And there are much more.

Answer (score 0):

**PHP** is an server side scripting language.Browser cant run php scripts
you can run it with a webserver such as: [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html)
or test it online on available sites like [this](http://writecodeonline.com/php/)